# ConcurrentHashMap wait for key possible?

Tags: java, collections, guava

i have multithread communication.
1 Thread is dispatching datas to other threads.

Main thread is pushing data:

Main Thread:
     ConcurrentHashMap map = Global.getInstance().getMap();
     //push data to some other thread
     map.put(1,"Test");

Thread 1:
     String data = map.get(1);
     //returns null directly , but i want to wait until data pushed

Thread 1 returns null if main thread doesn't push any data.
But i want to wait until i got data , 
how can i wait ?

TransferQueue is not good solution to my current implementation.
I have to do with ConcurrentHashMap.

Does someone know any solution?

Answer (score 9):

You can create a BlockingMap, something like this; depending on usage, you should also device a mechanism to remove unused keys and queues associated to them in order to avoid a memory leak.

```
public class BlockingMap<K, V> {
    private final Map<K, BlockingQueue<V>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private synchronized BlockingQueue<V> ensureQueueExists(K key) {
        //concurrentMap.putIfAbsent would require creating a new
        //blocking queue each time put or get is called
        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            return map.get(key);
        } else {
            BlockingQueue<V> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);
            map.put(key, queue);
            return queue;
        }
    }

    public boolean put(K key, V value, long timeout, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        BlockingQueue<V> queue = ensureQueueExists(key);
        try {
            return queue.offer(value, timeout, timeUnit);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    public V get(K key, long timeout, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        BlockingQueue<V> queue = ensureQueueExists(key);
        try {
            return queue.poll(timeout, timeUnit);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Since Java 8, `ensureQueueExists` can be written:

```
private synchronized BlockingQueue<V> ensureQueueExists(K key) {
    return map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1));
}
```

Comment: Nice, but since java 8 in this use case method putIfAbsent() is more convenient then computeIfAbsent(), it seems to me.

Comment: The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) says of `computeIfAbsent`: "The entire method invocation is performed atomically". So, I believe you can even drop the `synchronized` keyword unless I'm missing some subtlety.

Comment: This `put` implementation has the undesired effect of not overwriting existing keys.

Comment: I added this code to get it working:
```private void ensureQueueEmpty(BlockingQueue<V> queue) {
        if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                queue.remove();
            } catch (NoSuchElementException ignore) {
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void put(K key, V value) {
        BlockingQueue<V> queue = ensureQueueExists(key);
        ensureQueueEmpty(queue);
        queue.offer(value);
    }
```

Comment: What a solution.. All in one. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BlockingQueue` if you allowed to change your implementation, or use a wait/notify technique to wait and run when occupy.

```
  String value = null;
    while(true) {
        if((value = map.get(1)) != null) { // VARY IMPORTANT to use get and !=
            // work with value 
        } else {
            synchronized (map) {
                try {
                     map.wait();
                 } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
            }
        }
    }
```

and for producer:

```
    String value = "Test";
    map.put(1,value);
    synchronized (map) {
       map.notifyAll(); // or notify().
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

First, call `wait()` on Thread 1 right before it gets a value from the Map. You could then extend ConcurrentHashMap and override the `put()` method to `notify()` Thread 1 when new data is available.

Comment: with such aproach, you are synchronizing two threads. what the point of using `ConcurrentHashMap` if your two theads will be blocked by each other.

Comment: The author said he has to use `ConcurrentHashMap` so I'm constrained by that. A `Queue` would be a much better choice. That said, the two threads don't block on each other (properly written) because `Thread.wait()` releases its locks. This pattern is similar to how the blocking queue you suggested below works internally.