# Java how to get a map value in future?

Tags: java, multithreading

Here's pseudo code:

```
//-- Thread A
sender.send(requestId, request);
// Wait receiver to receive response for that requestId
return requestIdToResponseMap.get(requestId);


//--- Thread B
response = receiver.receive();
requestIdToResponseMap.put(response.requestId, response);
```

**Note**:
The call to downstream service is:

1. time consuming
2. **asynchronized** (i.e. response for request can only be mapped by **request-id**)

Let's say downstream service is a websocket client. The server sends messages and waits for responses.

About the **requestIdToResponseMap**, I tried 3 solutions:

1. Use a requestIdToLockMap to hold the locks, and use requestIdToResponseMap to hold the response values, but it seems complicated.
2. Use Map< String, Optional< Response>>, but Optional is immutable, I can not change its value. This doesn't work.
3. Use Map< String, Pair< Lock, Response>>, the receiver notifies the corresponding lock, then sender thread gets notified and retrieves the value.

So, for this kind of problem, what's the usual solution?

Comment: Can't the receiver respond to the sender?

Comment: @shmosel How? there needs to be a middleman structure I'm looking for.

Comment: The same way the receiver waits on the sender, the sender should be able to wait on the receiver.

Comment: requestIdToResponseMap can be thought as a Queue - you are doing a sync operation which will not work - you need to poll (requestIdToResponseMap) for the Id with some timeout

Comment: @user1428716 yes, that is what I'm doing, but a queue doesn't have key-value mapping. Ideally I should use a BlockingMap, but there's no official implementation.

Comment: Seems like a classic wait/notify scenario.

Comment: @shmosel yes, only special is here I need to identify corresponding response by requestId.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23920910/1553851) the BlockingMap you're referring to?

Comment: You can do this - Create two Sources - one is BlockingQueue ( Response Queue ) which will contain only the request ID - and another HashMap having the Response Payload with key as RequestId - Both operations would be in a sync block so that there is a consistency- operation to put in Queue can happen in last

Comment: One option is to keep another map of <key, synchronizer>.

Comment: @shmosel, Yes, I can use 2 map, but seems complicated. Actually, I think a mutable Optional may be the best way. It could act as a lock and a response value holder in the same time.

Comment: Or you can have the sender insert a `CompletableFuture` and wait on the receiver to fill it. Similar idea to yours, but it'll handle the synchronization automatically.

Comment: Do you actually need the map, or is it a tentative communication mechanism? It would help if you elaborated on your actual requirements.

Comment: @shmosel I don't really need map, the relationship of request and response is identified by a id, let's say it is request-id.

Comment: Are there multiple senders or receivers?

Comment: @shmosel the sender is a spring controller method, which receives requests and forwards request to downstream server, and waits response. There is only 1 sender currently.

Comment: Assuming the sender and receiver share some synchronized container (e.g., `CompletableFuture`), I don't see why the map is necessary at all.

Comment: It sounds like you may be better off using an `ExecutorService` instead of a blocking queue.

Comment: @shmosel the call to downstream service is not only time consuming but also asynchronized, and response for request can only be mapped by request-id.

Comment: @shmosel let me try ConcurrentHashMap<String, CompletableFuture>.

Comment: I don't see why you would need to map the response to the request. The sender knows which request he's dealing with, and the receiver doesn't need to.

Comment: @shmosel because the call to downstream is async, how receiver notifies the sender a response for a particular request is ready?

Comment: Because they're using a shared container. E.g.,`CompletableFuture<Response> future = new CompletableFuture<>(); sender.send(requestId, request, future); return future.get();` Where's the need for mapping?

Comment: receiver can get multiple responses, how does the future know which one is for the request?

Comment: Ah, you mean it's async on the receiver too. Well, then the receiver can keep his own map. No real difference I guess. But are you sure it really needs to be async on both ends?

Comment: @shmosel The protocol is STOMP over webosocket, I want the server initiates the request and downstream service (websocket client) responses it. I think the CompletableFuture is suitable for this.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't go into detail on your use case, so I'll answer the question generally:

Java has an entire [framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) for multi-threaded consumer-producer cases. If you find yourself thinking about locks and thread primitives, you're probably reinventing the wheel. Focus on the important stuff :-)

Here's a snippet to get you started:

```
 // create your thread pool, threads here will consume your "requests"
 ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
 // submit a request to the pool. This gets enqueued on a queue, until it is picked up by a thread. Returns a future- a reference to the uncompleted work
 Future<Response> future = threadPool.submit(new RequestTask<Response>(request, requestId));
 // wait for the work to complete
 Response response = future.get();
```

your `RequestTask` implements `Callable`:

```
   private static class RequestTask implements Callable<Response> {
        @Override
        public Response call() throws Exception {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Just to be clear, your producer thread is the "main" thread (A in your example) and the consumer is in the thread pool (thread B). You can increase your thread pool size (to a certain extent) to increase your request throughput.

There's tons of references about Java's ExecutorService and producer-consumer pattern. Remember that you have a queue in between producer and consumer threads, since you may produce requests faster than you can consume. It's unbounded by default, very important to remember that!

Let us know if you have any more questions.

Comment: I should add more details. The call to downstream service is not only time consuming but also asynchronized(i.e. response for request can only be mapped by request-id). That means RequestTask can't return a response corresponding to the initial request without looking up a mapping structure.

Comment: @user1633272 Why does RequestTask need a mapping structure? You can pass whatever state you want to RequestTask- you own it. If you need to store some additional state along with the task, just add it to your object (via constructor injection).

Comment: @user1633272 If you need to return additional information, just change your response type. E.g create a ResponseContainer which contains Response and Request metadata. If I understand your use case, Map is not the right data structure for this.

Answer (score 0):

Create map which will store reponsefuture which will be blocking if result is not available thread will wait .You can modify with other functionality like wait for how much time.

```
private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, ExecutorSeriveInstanceFuture> instanceMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, ExecutorSeriveInstanceFuture>();
```

customize Future so you can modify according to your use case.

```
private static class ExecutorSeriveInstanceFuture {
        private DBExecutorSerive dbExecutorSerive;
        private Throwable throwable;
        private Object lock = new Object();

        public DBExecutorSerive get() {
            if (dbExecutorSerive == null) {
                return dbExecutorSerive;
            }
            boolean restoreInterrupt = false;
            synchronized (lock) {
                while (dbExecutorSerive == null && throwable == null) {
                    try {
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        restoreInterrupt = true;
                    }
                }

            }
            if (restoreInterrupt) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            if (dbExecutorSerive != null) {
                return dbExecutorSerive;
            }
            throw new IllegalStateException(throwable);
        }

        public void set(DBExecutorSerive dbExecutorSerive) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                this.dbExecutorSerive = dbExecutorSerive;
                lock.notifyAll();
            }
        }

        public void setFailure(Throwable throwable) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                this.throwable = throwable;
                lock.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
```