# Producer/Consumer (sort of) with concurrenthashmap and Java threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I have one thread writing to my concurrenthashmap, and another thread reading these blocks (not removing them).

A similiar question was given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23917818/concurrenthashmap-wait-for-key-possible) that almost provides a solution, but doesn't quite apply to my situation.

I have this class:

```
public class BlockStore {

    private ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Long> blockToOffset = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile;


    public BlockStore(RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile, long fileLength) throws IOException {
        this.randomAccessFile = randomAccessFile;
        randomAccessFile.setLength(fileLength);
    }

    public boolean hasBlock(int blockNumber) {
        return blockToOffset.containsKey(blockNumber);
    }

    public void getBlock(int blockNumber, byte[] buffer) throws BlockNotFoundException, IOException {
        if (hasBlock(blockNumber)) {
            long offset = blockToOffset.get(blockNumber);
            randomAccessFile.seek(offset);
            randomAccessFile.readFully(buffer);
        } else throw new BlockNotFoundException();
    }

    public void writeBlock(int blockNumber, byte[] buffer) throws IOException {
        long offset = blockNumber * NodeUtil.FILE_BUFFER_SIZE;
        randomAccessFile.seek(offset);
        randomAccessFile.write(buffer);
        blockToOffset.put(blockNumber, offset);
        blockToOffset.notifyAll();
    }

    public boolean allFilesReceived() throws IOException {
        double expectedNumberOfBlocks = Math.ceil(((double) randomAccessFile.length()/NodeUtil.FILE_BUFFER_SIZE));
        return expectedNumberOfBlocks == blockToOffset.size();
    }
}
```

- Thread1 provides blocks to the blockstore, which are indexed in the concurrenthashmap. These blocks are an abstraction of actual byte[] written to a file. That block is empty until written to.
- Thread2 tries to get a block at index i, if it doesn't exist, it should wait until it does and retrieve it. Thread 2 may access the same block again later, so it cannot be removed.

E.g. given the following situation

1: thread2.getBlock(0, emtpyBuff) // block doesn't exist so thread waits
2. thread1.writeBlock(0, buffWithData) // writes data block to file, adds  block to hashmap.
3: thread2 is notified that block now exists, retrieves offset from hashmap, writes corresponding file block to emptyBuff, and goes on to do stuff.

The main difference between the this and the other question is that I'm not wanting to return the value of the hashmap directly, but perform further operations on it within the blockstore class to fetch the actual file data.

Thanks! :)

EDIT:

I've considered simply polling the blockstore from thread2 until a return value is given, but that results in a lot of unecessary CPU usage.

Comment: Did you considered usage of `BlockingQueue`? You could put objects with two fields (`blockNumber`, `offset`) in a queue in one thread and poll then in another.

Comment: @Ivan thanks for commenting! I've considered a similiar solution (see the last-minute edit), but I was hoping to avoid polling the resource in any way due to the busy-waiting behaviour that would increase CPU usage.

Comment: `BlockingQueue` has convenient methods `poll(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` which blocks up until timeout if no elements available in the queue. So you could use `poll(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` to wait. And if you get `null` it means that no elements were available in the queue and you are done.

Comment: @Ivan I'll try that and get back to you! :)

Comment: @Ivan I've considered the BlockingQueue but there's a slight problem with the poll() methods: it removes the object from the queue once it becomes available. According to the docs, there doesn't seem to be a peek() equivalent that comes with a timeout which would solve this problem. Potentially I could just add a new queue back into the map, but this seems like an ineffeciency that could be avoided.

Comment: Do you need to keep those elements in a map/queue after processing? I see that you write data to file and then put object to `map` and in another thread you get object from `map` and read that chunk from file.

Comment: @Ivan It's possible that the same elements will be read again later, but they are always only written once.

Comment: You could use `Map<Integer, Future<Integer>>` and `ExecutorService`. First thread creates `Callable<Integer>` object, submits it to `ExecutorService` and puts that `Future<Integer>` into the map. The second thread gets `Future<Integer>` from the map and executes `get()`. If result is not ready it blocks in `get()` until computation is completed. Subsequent calls to `get()` for the same `Future` will return immediately.

Comment: @Ivan that sounds perfect! I'll try it out now.

Comment: @Ivan I'm struggling a bit to actually implement this, could you provide some pseudo-code to make it clearer?

Comment: Added as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's not a 'nice' solution for this problem, and so I adapted the referenced question to match my own. This is only a safe solution when one thread is reading from the blocking queue as the poll then return value in getBlock() is not thread safe.

```
public class BlockStore {

    private ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, BlockingQueue<Long>> blockToOffset = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile;

    public BlockStore(RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile, long fileLength) throws IOException {
        this.randomAccessFile = randomAccessFile;
        randomAccessFile.setLength(fileLength);
    }

    private synchronized BlockingQueue<Long> ensureQueueExists(int key) {
        if (blockToOffset.containsKey(key)) {
            return blockToOffset.get(key);
        } else {
            BlockingQueue<Long> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);
            blockToOffset.put(key, queue);
            return queue;
        }
    }

    public void getBlock(int blockNumber, byte[] buffer) {
        BlockingQueue<Long> queue = ensureQueueExists(blockNumber);
        try {
            long offset = queue.poll(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            queue.add(offset); // Put offset back into queue. Since get will only be called by one thread, this does not result in a race condition
            randomAccessFile.seek(offset);
            randomAccessFile.readFully(buffer);
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void writeBlock(int blockNumber, byte[] buffer) throws IOException {
        BlockingQueue<Long> queue = ensureQueueExists(blockNumber);
        long offset = blockNumber * NodeUtil.FILE_BUFFER_SIZE;
        randomAccessFile.seek(offset);
        randomAccessFile.write(buffer);
        queue.add(offset);
        blockToOffset.put(blockNumber, queue);
    }

    public boolean allFilesReceived() throws IOException {
        double expectedNumberOfBlocks = Math.ceil(((double) randomAccessFile.length()/NodeUtil.FILE_BUFFER_SIZE));
        return expectedNumberOfBlocks == blockToOffset.size();
    }
}
```